# How to switch to a different user on same agent to run a particular task in AzureDevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have a pipeline with 6 tasks in one job, this job runs on agent01(self-hosted), there are two users, user1 and user2(more privileges) on agent01.

My requirement is, my pipeline job running on agent01 must use user1 for task 1,2,3 and use2 for  task 4,5,6. How to achieve this ? please suggest.

Comment: don't think you can, it will run with the user you configured in the agent. you can split the job to 2 phases, each phase will run in another agent.

Comment: Can you share the current state of your pipeline? those users refer to what? to the operating system?

Comment: Hi @Bruno .. yes .. they are OS users.

Answer (score 0):

> How to switch to a different user on same agent to run a particular
> task in AzureDevOps pipeline

I'm afraid this is impossible to achieve. When pipeline is running, in the Initialize job step, the user has been determined, and we cannot assign another user to the tasks.

[image]

As Shayki suggested in the comment, you can split the job into two jobs and use different agents to run.

Comment: Hi Hugh Lin ... i will try what you suggested. I don't have option to spilt the job into two, as of now, only one agent.

Comment: @HughLin can the Job specify what user should it use ? or it's configured by the agent itself?